# jQuery Masonry - Issue with Fluid layout

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am working on a site which was made by another developer using the jQuery Masonry plugin. The site is working fine but the layout is responsive. The problem here is that I need to add some elements which are non responsive and due to this I need to make the whole site non responsive.

The site contains lots of style sheets and JavaScripts, so I don't know where to start and what code to supply as reference.

But it would be helpful if someone can suggest obvious ways by which I can make the layout non-responsive.

So far I have removed all the @media elements from style sheets...but this hasn't worked...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by setting a fixed width on the container which holds the masonry divs..

```
<div id="container" class="masonry" style="width: 1150px !important;">
.....
.....
</div>
```

Hope this helps someone..